# How to test a module in odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm starting to learn odoo modules developing
so I created a module named "vetclinic" in `odoo/addons`

it contains 4 files inside which are:

1. **init**.py
2. **openerp**.py
3. vetclinic.py
4. vetclinic_view.xml

and I created models inside them which I want to test their output.

How could I test it?

I tried this command

```
./openerp-server --addons-path=addons -d opt-test -i vetclinic
```

and I got this error

```
WARNING opt-test openerp.modules.loading: invalid module names, ignored: vetclinic
```

Comment: It should `__init__.py` and `__openerp__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The files you have created do note form a proper Odoo module. In order for them to do so you must rename a couple of them:

- `init.py` becomes `__init__.py`
- `openerp.py`becomes `__openerp__.py`

Please refer to the [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html) site for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script:

install_vetclinic.sh @/home/user/

```sh
rm -r /odoo/odoo-server/addons/vetclinic/
mv vetclinic /odoo/odoo-server/addons/
/etc/init.d/odoo-server restart
```

update.sh @anywhere (on your desktop maybe)

```sh
scp -rP 22 vetclinic user@serverip:~
ssh user@serverip sudo ./install_vetclinic.sh
```

Finaly, you need to create an SSH-Key for your script.
Do this like here:

[SSH-Key Tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

Whenever you want to update your module, use the script, then go to Apps in Odoo and update your module.

Answer (score -1):

`--addons-path` refers to the modules of odoo which includes all the core modules from odoo as well as custom modules addons path. Odoo core modules are split into two paths. Let's say your addons are located in `opt` directory than your addons path would be like as follows:

```
--addons-path=/opt/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo/openerp/addons,/opt/my_custom_addons_path
```

Here you can see that first two paths are of core modules of odoo and the last one is of the custom addons path where all the custom addons are located.

Comment: The files do not make a proper python module.